# Auto generate test numbers in Postman

Tags: postman

as a practice I number my Postman tests for organization because some of my test suites can be sizeable. This works great until I have to add or remove tests; when that happens, I have to manually go in and re-number my tests. I was wondering if anyone has any recommended bash scripts that could help with the tasks of creating the numbers from the outset and updating them when anything changes?

[image: sample_test_suite]